# theGate infrared touch screen doesn't work on 14.04 LTS

Tags: touchscreen

We have smart boards at school and we use it for education.

It's simply a large screen and a hidden computer which is connected to a frame, including theGate infrared touch screen module.

It works perfectly with win7. I installed ubuntu 14.04 LTS to a flash drive. It works wonderfully but the touch screen doesn't work.

I asked new drivers from the Gate Technologies and they've sent me a tar.gz file.

There are several files in it and a setupforubuntu.sh file.

I installed on terminal as superuser, but it doesn't work anyway. I'm attaching the console message. What can I do? Can you help me?

```
Begin to setup the Touchscreen driver.
(I) Extract Touchscreen driver archive to /usr/local/thegate
/usr/local/thegate.
(I) Copy configuration file to /etc.
(I) Create calib link in /usr/bin.
(I) The /usr/local/thegate/thegate.init has been added in /etc/rc.local.
(I) Check X window version: 6.9.0 ~ 7.2.0
(I) Copy X module: x69/thegate_drv.so to /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input.
cp: `/usr/local/thegate/Module/x69/thegate_drv.so' durumlanamadı: Böyle bir dosya ya da dizin yok
(I) Removed Touchscreen driver archive from /usr/local/thegate.
(I) Searching the X module of touch device.
(E) The driver archive has been removed already.
```